# Algorithm to draw direction of edge

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I am developing graph application. In app window there are vertices conneted by edges. User is able to move vertex, and as he do it edge also moves. I am having problem to find pattern to draw arrow representing edge direction depending on both vertex positions.

Here's an example.

Lets say vertex has `width/height = 20px;` Edge is drawn from center of Vertex1 to center of Vertex2.

```
Vertex1.position = new Point(0,0);
Vertex2.position = new Point(100,0);
Edge.point1 = new Point(10,10);
Edge.point2 = new Point(110,10);
//Arrow representing direction from Vertex1 to Vertex2
Arrow.point1 = new Point(100,10);
Arrow.point2 = new Point(90,20);
Arrow.point3 = new Point(90,0);
```

Question is: Knowing position of edge start/end points, how to calculate arrow points?

Comment: 1) Define arrow points in radial terms (angle/distance) relative to the point (the top), 2) calculate angle of the vector connecting your vertices (angle to either x or y axis, doesn't matter), 3) Depending on which angle you took, add or subtract your arrow point angles from it, 4) Using sin and cos, calculate x and y offset from the top arrow point for each of the arrow (left right) points, 5) add those values to the top arrow point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say edge's starting point has coordinates `(ax, ay)`, ending point `(bx, by)`, the vertex has radius `w`, your arrow has the length of its pointer `l` and the angle between the arrow edges `alpha`
Then in pseudocode:

```
ex := (bx - ax) 
ey := (by - ay) 
ex := ex / sqrt(ex^2 + ey^2)
ey := ey / sqrt(ex^2 + ey^2)
```

The first point of the arrow:

```
a1x := bx - w * ex
a1y := by - w * ey
```

The second point of the arrow:

```
a2x := bx - (w + l) * ex + l * tg(alpha/2) * ey
a2y := by - (w + l) * ey - l * tg(alpha/2) * ex
```

The third point of the arrow:

```
a3x := bx - (w + l) * ex - l * tg(alpha/2) * ey
a3y := by - (w + l) * ey + l * tg(alpha/2) * ex
```

Sorry for such poor formatting, I don't know how to use mathematical markup here. And I hope I didn't make any errors in the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You didn't point at your application type. If you use WinForms [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/DrawArrow.htm) can be useful. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.linecap.aspx) is MSDN article about `LineCap`.